# Unity-Firebase Realtime Database - OrderByChild or OrderByValue does not work

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I try to develop a leaderboard system using Firebase Realtime Database using Unity.

I can store and load the score values, everything works ok.
However, when I try to retrieve the scores in order, I cannot manage to do. I do as exactly described in:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/retrieve-data#sort_data

The structure of the data in my firebase console is as follows:

### [image]

My "orderByChild" using code is as below:

```
// Set the leaderboard reference
        m_leaderBoardDBReference = mDatabaseReference.Child ("Users");

        // Get the data, order by child "highScore"
        m_leaderBoardDBReference.OrderByChild("highScore").GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
            if (task.IsFaulted) {
                // Handle the error...
                Debug.Log("Data " + lbAddress + " not found");
            }else if (task.IsCompleted) {
                DataSnapshot snapshot = task.Result;
                // Print the raw json value of the leaderboard data
                Debug.Log("Leaderboard Raw Json Value\n");
                Debug.Log(snapshot.GetRawJsonValue());
            }
        });
```

I get the following result:

```
Leaderboard Raw Json Value
{"user3":{"highScore":49},"user4":{"highScore":0},"user5":{"highScore":69},"user6":{"highScore":155}}
```

In other words, it is **not** properly ordered.

I also tried the "OrderByValue" version as follows:

```
// Set the leaderboard reference
    m_leaderBoardDBReference = mDatabaseReference.Child ("Contests/AprilMay");

    // Get the data, order by value

m_leaderBoardDBReference.OrderByValue().GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
            if (task.IsFaulted) {
                // Handle the error...
                Debug.Log("Data " + lbAddress + " not found");
            }else if (task.IsCompleted) {
                DataSnapshot snapshot = task.Result;
                // Print the raw json value of the leaderboard data
                Debug.Log("Leaderboard Raw Json Value\n");
                Debug.Log(snapshot.GetRawJsonValue());
            }
        });
```

The structure:

[image]

The output:

```
Leaderboard Raw Json Value
{"dummy":0,"user3":240,"user5":69,"user6":155}
```

Comment: did you ever manage to resolve this fercis

Comment: Ah yes Tom, snapshot.GetRawJsonValue() was not the correct statement. Raw JSON Value is always unorderdered. I had to write a for loop traversing snapshot.children
"
 foreach (DataSnapshot childSnapshot in topItemsSnapshot.Children)
"
And use  childSnapshot.Key() and childSnapshot.Value() . That children are ordered and works well.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53360330/orderbychild-wont-order-firebase-realtime-database/53363129#53363129  Same issue i had, with more details and example for the answer.

Comment: @fercis Hi new to firebase. Was wondering if you can direct me to a tutorial on how to create the child nodes to structure my JSON tree?