# OrderByChild wont order, Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I use Firebase Realtime Database.
I have the following leaderboard data in the Database:

```
Leaders:
        0
           Name: Michal
           Score: 40
        1
           Name: David
           Score: 35
        2
           Name: Rob
           Score: 53
```

[image]

I am reading the data which works fine besides the `OrderByChild` won't sort.
I assume it is related to me saving with Array numbering.

**NOTE**: I do not use any bizzare method to save the data with array, but actually google example using Transactions with Unity, having said that, i expect the `OrderByChild` to work. [Transactions, see bottom of screen](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/save-data)

This is the code that retrieves the data:

```
  FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance
          .GetReference("Leaders").OrderByChild("score").GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
                    {
                        if (task.IsFaulted)
                        {
                            Debug.LogError("error in reading LeaderBoard from DB");
                            return;
                        }
                        else if (task.IsCompleted)
                        {
                            Debug.Log("Received values for Leaders.");
                            string JsonLeaderBaord = task.Result.GetRawJsonValue();
                            callback(JsonLeaderBaord);
                        }
                    }
```

I did try to add the `onIndex` rule, but still the same, it ignores the ordering.

Comment: can you send screenshot of your real firebase data? maybe with hidden names ?

Comment: @laltin Added photo of real data in firebase

Comment: it may be an issue with your keys being indexes of an array. Firebase doesn't suggest storing arrays. So my suggestion would be change key from number (0, 1, ..) to some strings

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you query the database like this:

```
FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance
      .GetReference("Leaders").OrderByChild("score").GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
```

Firebase returns a snapshot with the request information in the right order. But when you then call:

```
string JsonLeaderBaord = task.Result.GetRawJsonValue();
```

It has to convert the snapshot to JSON data. And in JSON the order of child nodes is by definition undefined, so you lose information about the order.

To process the leaderboard in the correct order, use the built-in methods to loop over the snapshot:

```
foreach (DataSnapshot leader in snapshot.Children) {
    Debug.Log("Received value for leader: "+leader.Child("Score").Value);
}
```

Comment: I get you, thanks! Pity it can't work with GetRawJsonValue as i serialize it. Ended up sorting internally from code, unless someone finds a better answer, this is the accepted one.